# Probability of winning half the matchups in a dance competition

Tags: probability, proof-writing, combinatorial-proofs

Here's the problem I'm stuck on:

There are d people competing in a dance competition. Each dancer will compete in a dance-off with everyone else in the competition. They are all equally skilled and have an equal chance of winning any matchup. What is the probability that dancer 1 will win exactly half of their dance matchups? You must prove your answer, do not merely give examples. Assume d is odd.

So, I've figured out that half of the dance matchups for a dancer will be (d-1)/2. I think there should be a total of d(d-1)/2 matchups, and each dance off has a 1/2 probability of being either a win or a loss. But I also think each dancer's number of wins is not independent of the other's numbers of wins, so I am confused on how I can find out the probability that a person will win exactly half of their dances by combining my information somehow.

Comment: "But I also think each dancer's number of wins is not independent of the other's numbers of wins". Well if you only pay attention to the amount of wins person 1 has, you shouldn't care about other's wins and losses.

Comment: I'm certainly no statistician or probability guru, but I have wondered something similar to this. I *think* the situation is (probability wise) exactly the same as flipping a coin $n$ times and expecting $\frac{n}{2}$ heads. [This](https://www.omnicalculator.com/statistics/coin-flip-probability) will calculate that, $n$ flips equals $n$ dancers. DON'T TAKE MY WORD FOR IT. Make sure *you* and *others* think this is correct

Comment: Thank you both, the second part of the problem is asking us to find a upper bound on the probability of at least n dancers winning exactly half of the match ups, so I thought the distinction of who wins and who loses would be relevant to this part, but you all may be right. It does seem to me like the 1 dancer wouldn't care about other combinations, only the specific ones where he wins half, but know I'm confused on the combinations/outcomes again.